# Why do I need the extra pramaters?

Tags: extjs

In Ext, I saw the below function is called by a click listener in the init function. I'm just curious that why I need the item, t, index or eOpts to make it work. Those parameters seems not being used in this function, but if I remove them, it gives me an error says:

```
onRowClickAttributes: function( t, rec, item, index, e, eOpts ) {
    if( e.getTarget().className.indexOf( 'edit-me' ) !== -1 ) {
        this.openEditor( rec );
    } else if( e.getTarget().className.indexOf( 'delete-me' ) !== -1 ) {
        this.deleteAttributes( [ rec ] );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the function is used as an event listener, apparently for the `rowclick` event of a grid view.

When the grid view fires the event (i.e. after a row was clicked), the function will be called with the defined parameters (see [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.View-event-itemclick)). This is managed by the framework and supposed to include everything which is somehow related to the event and therefore *might* be helpful for the developer.

Since the parameters are passed exactly in the order as written in the documentation and the developer has no influence on this order, you cannot omit `t` in order to use `rec` and you cannot omit `item` or `index` in order to use `e`.

You could, however, omit the last parameter `eOpts` as it is not used in your function and there are no further parameters following.

```
onRowClickAttributes: function( t, rec, item, index, e ) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters are only known to this function by the order in which they are presented.  So a call to

```
onRowClickAttributes(null, rec, null, null, e);
```

will pass in rec and e only.

Is that what you were getting at?

Comment: No, I have tried this, and it gives me some error says the null is unexpected token.